# Setting vars in composition API?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm using vue 3 composition api and I am struggling understanding setting vars, if I should use myVar.value or not?

For example, how should the following be set?

```
<script setup>

const active = ref(false);

function show(){
    active = true;
    active.value = true;
    this.active = true;
}
```

Which way?

Comment: It's a ref, so `active.value = true`, as explained in the documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) and [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref)

Comment: @yoduh thanks, is that even with script setup?

Comment: yes, that's how you update a ref with script setup or setup function

Answer (score 0):

In the script tag, state defined using `ref()` should be accessed using `.value` :

```html
<script setup>
const active = ref(false)

function show() {
    active.value = true
}
</script>
```

In the template, state can be accessed directly :

```html
<template>
    <h1 v-if="active">Hello, World!</h1>
</template>
```

If using defining state using `reactive()`, `.value` is not used :

```html
<script setup>
    const greetings = reactive({ 'classic': 'Hello, World! })
    console.log(greetings.classic)
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <h1>{{ greetings.classic }}</h1>
</template>
```

Documentation: [Vue 3 Reactivity API: Core](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html)